# How can I update a python source code installation (made by myself) to the latest version in Linux?

Tags: python, installation, upgrade, python-3.8

I use an Ubuntu based system (Pop!_OS 20.04) and I installed Python 3.8.5 via source code. Since python 3.8.6 was released, I want to upgrade my version to the latest one, but I couldn't find any tutorial on the internet about this.

So I asking how can I update my Python version, but without installing a third version (since the system already had a dedicated python installation, which isn't recommended using for personal purposes, and I managed to install a python version for my personal use), like a normal upgrade.

Ps:

1. This is my first question here, so sorry for any kind of inconvenience by my part.
2. English is not my principal language, so if you'd have some questions or corrections about my explanation, feel free to tell me!

Comment: Does https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#getting-and-installing-the-latest-version-of-python not help?

Comment: No, i already read this file, and i didn't realize what i need to do to upgrade a source python installation. If this file does have a solution for my problem, i would be very grateful if you could point the section where the solution is.